# Lua: What's the difference between null and nil?

Tags: lua, null, luainterface

I'm developing a plugin for [Oxide 2](http://rustoxide.com/). I've been learning from other plugins and I've noticed that some of them use `null` instead of `nil`. For example:

```
if args[1] == null then
```

Oxide 2 is written in C#, so I assume that `null` is defined in C# or in Lua Interface.

Is there any difference between them?

---

**Update:**
I've somewhere read that it can be used for check, if MySQL column is `NULL`. Is that true?

Comment: You mean `var = nil` as well as `var = null`? Barring any special embedded details `null` is just a variable (that probably has no value and so will be `nil`) but could be assigned to normally otherwise. Try `print(null); null = "foo"; print(null)` in a normal lua interpreter for example.

Comment: @EtanReisner At first it printed `null`, but after modification it printed `foo`. So it seems to be a normal variable.

Comment: In normal lua it is. I can't speak to what Oxide did when they embedded it or if some library uses `null` as some special sentinel.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`nil` is a value in the Lua language.

`null` is a variable name. What value does it contain? You can easily check that. We cannot. If it turns out to be `nil`, then using `null` is pointless, probably a mistake made by someone context switching between C# and Lua code which accidentally works because an undefined variable will evaluate to `nil`.